# Identifying the control's container (GroupBox, etc.) dynamically

Tags: c#, .net, windows, winforms

I'm dynamically generating a Windows Forms form by reading an XML file. (Actually I have a separate tool developed to serialize a Windows Forms form and its components.)

How do I find out in which container control each control is in?

For example, if I'm dynamically creating a label I want to find if it is inside a group box or any container. Is there a property available for it?

Comment: Dynamic form generation using WinForms is very difficult to get right - I strongly suggest learning WPF or finding someone who knows WPF, as WPF makes it easy.

Comment: Can you provide a sample of the code which is creating the Label?  The label isn't inside any container until you add it to one - at that point you will know which container it's in.

Comment: @Greg.. Actually I'm serializing a windows form with controls using another program. There I have to select the particular property and then write it. After that I am reading that XML in another program and dynamically creating the form. To do that I have to identify the correct property. As suggested here I'm trying with the "Parent" property. I'll let u know if it's correct. Thnx every1.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

That would be `mycontrol.Parent`.

Answer (score 6):

Have a look at

[Control.Parent Property](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.forms.control.parent.aspx)

Comment: Thanks alot.Sorry I can mark only 1 correct answer here. My upvotes are finished so I will upvote this 2morrow. Thanks alot.

Comment: @JCTLK -- I think he deserves the accept =) I was lazy and just wrote one line, where he actually looked up the URL.

Answer (score 1):

The controls of .NET are having a property called Parent.
The controls inside the group panel are set to their parent as the Group box name.

Answer (score 0):

First, you can find a group box, say for example:

```
groupbox x
```

After that, find a label, like

```
(Label) x.findControl("labelID").
```

You can try it like this.